# How to make an operation to every element of a list

Tags: prolog

I find myself narrowing a (very simple) problem more and more.

Let's say I have this operation: `listsplit([H1,H2,H3|T], H1,H2,H3, T).`

Which gives me the first three elements of a list. I want a program, cells, to travel an input list and make (at least that ONE operation!!) to every element of the list.

So I have something like:

```
cells(Input, Result):-
   cellsBody(Input, [], Result).

cellsBody([],Result,Result).
cellsBody([Head|Input], Acc, [Headd|Result]):-
   listsplit(Input,H1,H2,H3,_),
   cellsBody(Input, [OutputBody|Acc], Result).
```

I have that code because I have used many I've seen as examples that go like that to travel a list. They separate head from body and go on. I fail to see how this is done in prolog. I tried changing variable names, so that they would match (as I would do in other languages), and I've tried to make the problem as simple as possible.

So, how do I travel a list AND make operations to every element (that I choose to, starting with the first one, the head).

Edit: Examples of what I want to archieve:

I get an input list like oxo, oxxxo, oxoxo, so on. I then apply a rule to the first three elements, then the next three, and so on, and while I do that I add the result of the rule to another list that I return (which is why I am trying to use the accumulator).

Comment: See the family of [tag:meta-predicate]s `maplist/N`: Describe the relation for a single element, and then use `maplist/3` to apply the relation to lists of such elements.

Comment: Quite far away from my level right now, sadly. Prolog so far feels like having every tool available and not knowing how to use anything at all. Damn frustrating. Thanks @mat though, trying to wrap my head arround those new concepts, just in case

Comment: In case you cannot even state the relation for a *single* element, how do you expect to attack the more general case of *multiple* elements? Try stating the relation for a single element. My guess is that you will see from this that you have some serious misconceptions about the relation you want to describe. In concreto, my guess is that yours is *not* a relation that you can implement in the way you describe ("travel a list and make operations to every element"). If that were the case, you could say what such an operation looks like for *one* element, no?

Comment: I am probably not explaining myself properly, but for one element is very easy. I have to take 3 parameters as input and apply a rule to them (like: rule(o,o,x,x), being the last the result. So, if I have a list of elements, o's and x's, I have to find the rule for each of them, and with the results, build a list. Not sure if that counts as statement because frankly I don't know if we are talking about the same thing at all. I guess we are but not sure.

Comment: @keont perhaps if you could show some actual examples (in your question, not in a comment) of what you intend your predicate to do that would help clarify (at least for me, since my pea brain isn't quite seeing what it is you're trying to achieve).

Comment: I just did @lurker hope it helps. I can add a lot more info, anything required really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost got it. Keeping your predicate cells/2 as is, think about the special cases first: The lists `[]`, `[_]`, `[_,_]` haven't got three elements, so whatever operation you have in mind for those three elements, there's nothing to do in these cases. Otherwise you have a recursive rule to do what you intend to.

Looking at listsplit/5: you can do that directly in the head of the recursive rule, no need for an extra predicate. Then you have one or more goals for your intended operation. For the sake of an example let's say packaging the 3 head elements as a triplet. And of course the relation must hold for the tail `T` of the list too. Then your code might look something like that:

```
cellsBody([],Result,Result).
cellsBody([_],Result,Result).
cellsBody([_,_],Result,Result).
cellsBody([H1,H2,H3|T], Acc, Result):-   % the first 3 elements
   Triplet=(H1,H2,H3),                   % at least ONE operation with them
   cellsBody(T, [Triplet|Acc], Result).
```

Example queries:

```
   ?- cells([],Result).
Result = []
   ?- cells([1],Result).
Result = []
   ?- cells([1,2],Result).
Result = []
   ?- cells([1,2,3],Result).
Result = [(1,2,3)]
   ?- cells([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],Result).
Result = [(4,5,6),(1,2,3)]
```

Of course, if the intended operation is as simple as in the above example, you don't need an extra goal for it: You can do that directly in the recursive goal:

```
cellsBody([H1,H2,H3|T], Acc, Result):-
   cellsBody(T, [(H1,H2,H3)|Acc], Result).
```

Comment: First things first. You are correct I do want to do something more in between. What I want to do is to call to rule(H1,H2,H3,Output), and put that in the Acc. It WOULD be this way, right? Or would I need something else? You are EXACTLY right, I was now struggling with those rare cases. You mean to tell me you can put more than one stop condition?? Hum. I'm going to try go from here. And yeah, I knew there was some way to not use listsplit, but couldn't come up with one.

Comment: @keont: Yes, in that case you would write `[Output|Acc]` as 2nd argument of the recursive goal. As for the rare cases: they are in fact not that rare. If you take *any* list of length>=3 and repeatedly take away the first 3 elements, you end up with `[]`, `[_]` or `[_,_]`. So, procedurally speaking, you *need* those 3 cases to end the recursion.

Comment: yeah that's what I've been trying to fix all this evening, when I debugged I saw and I was like, how do I unify those 3 types of lists (tbf I didn't get to the empty list but putting different inputs I did see the 1 and 2 elements failing badly, so thanks again!!!!!!)